# Is it possible to create an SQL database table in an Azure ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create an Azure ARM template that will create an SQL server, SQL database and a table with it's columns included, but I keep getting errors when deploying.

Here is my template:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "serverName": {
        "defaultValue": "ServerTest",
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The name of the SQL logical server."
        }
    },
    "sqlDBName": {
        "defaultValue": "DatabaseTest",
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The name of the SQL Database."
        }
    },
    "location": {
        "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Location for all resources."
        }
    },
    "tableName": {
        "defaultValue": "MyTable",
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the table to be created."
        }
    }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
        "apiVersion": "2022-05-01-preview",
        "name": "[parameters('serverName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
            "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
            "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorLoginPassword')]"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
        "apiVersion": "2022-05-01-preview",
        "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('serverName'), parameters('sqlDBName'))]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName'))]"
        ],
        "sku": {
            "name": "Standard",
            "tier": "Standard"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/tables",
        "apiVersion": "2022-05-01-preview",
        "name": "[format('{0}/{1}/{2}', parameters('serverName'), parameters('sqlDBName'), parameters('tableName'))]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', parameters('serverName'), parameters('sqlDBName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "columns": [
                {
                    "name": "ID",
                    "type": "int"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Description",
                    "type": "nvarchar",
                    "maxLength": 255
                }
            ]
        },
        "resources": []
    }
],
"outputs": {
    "hostname": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "Template install complete"
    }
}
```

}

Here is the error I'm receiving when deploying:

```
The specified resource '/tables/MyTable' was not found. (Code: ResourceNotFound)
```

I've tried including dependsOn, but for some reason the table is not deploying.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for your issue, I found a way to deploy a SQL database, Server with a table by importing it from an existing database as a `.bacpac` file included in it using an ARM template, as described in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71124664/19785512) by @VenkateshDodda.

*Saying that, I tried below code in my environment and it worked as follows:*

```bash
{

  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters":
  {
    "administratorLogin":
    {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "administratorLoginPassword":
    {
      "type": "securestring"
    },
    "databaseName":
    {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "location":
    {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "_artifactsLocationSasToken":
    {
      "type": "securestring"
    }
  },
  "variables":
  {
    "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
    "edition": "Premium",
    "maxSizeBytes": "xxxxx",
    "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "P1",
    "storageKeyType": "SharedAccessKey",
    "version": "12.0",
    "serverName": "[concat('sqlnewserver', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
  },
  "resources":
  [
    {
      "name": "[variables('serverName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties":
      {
        "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorLoginPassword')]",
        "version": "[variables('version')]"
      },
      "resources":
      [
        {
          "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
          "type": "firewallrules",
          "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "dependsOn":
          [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('serverName'))]"
          ],
          "properties":
          {
            "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
            "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "[parameters('databaseName')]",
          "type": "databases",
          "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "dependsOn":
          [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('serverName'))]"
          ],
          "properties":
          {
            "collation": "[variables('collation')]",
            "edition": "[variables('edition')]",
            "maxSizeBytes": "[variables('maxSizeBytes')]",
            "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "[variables('requestedServiceObjectiveName')]"
          },
          "resources":
          [
            {
              "name": "Import",
              "type": "extensions",
              "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
              "dependsOn":
              [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('serverName'), '/databases/', parameters('databaseName'))]"
              ],
              "properties":
              {
                "storageKeyType": "[variables('storageKeyType')]",
                "storageKey": "[parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')]",
                "storageUri": "https://newjsbr.blob.core.windows.net/lat/76488879.md",
                "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
                "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorLoginPassword')]",
                "operationMode": "Import"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note:** Pass blob Uri of the `bacpac` file under `"storageUri"` property. For creating and importing the bacpac file, steps detailed in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kaevans/deploy-bacpac-to-azure-sql-database-using-arm).

*After successfully building your code, it will prompt you for the below parameters before deploying it. Otherwise, you can add `parameters.json` file as detailed in the above referenced SO*

[image]